LINK2001,and LINK1120 errors visual studio 2022 CLR empty project
i am currently working on a web browser on visual studio 2022 and every time I execute the program these errors show up LINK2001 unresolved external symbol main and LINK1120 1 unresolved externals.
So what I thought  was meant by 'external symbol' was the entry point we write at the begining of a program when we Select the Configuration Properties > Linker > Advanced property page and then we modify the Entry Point property
I tried looking up other entry points other than main
at so many websites and i wrote them but I didn't get results so i searched for tutorials but they are all in c# or visual basic or from a long time ago ( and still not in c++) I didn't find helpful answers
so my question is what entry point should I write?

C++ CLR(.Net Framework) project needs a different main entry point.
Cpp:
#include "MyForm.h"//Winform header


using namespace Project1;//winform namespace

[STAThread]
int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Project1::MyForm form;//Winform namespace
    Application::Run(% form);
    return  0;
}


What LINK2001 means is that the linker was unable to find the definition of the function main(). This could mean one of two things has happened. Either you have not created the main function or the file containing the main function is not available to the linker. I am going to assume it is the latter. What you need to do is make sure that the file containing main() is properly visible in your project. With out extra information on how you have the project configured I cannot give anything more specific.
Changing the entry point will not help you as what you are effectively doing is renaming main(). If you can't find the definition of main() in the first place renaming it won't help.
You can ignore LINK1120 as it is simply telling you how many LINK2001 errors occurred.
